# Converting pcl::PointCloud to Eigen::MatrixBase

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen, point-cloud-library

I am trying to run ICP algorithm from [this](https://sparseicp.googlecode.com/git/ICP.h) header. The function at line:260 has the declaration as

```
template <typename Derived1, typename Derived2>
void point_to_point(Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived1>& X,
                    Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived2>& Y,
                    Parameters par = Parameters()) {
```

I want to apply this algorithm on my two `pcl::PointCloud`s but it accepts `Eigen::MatrixBase`. I tried to call this function as follows

```
Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Matrix<double,3,1,Eigen::RowMajor,3,100>> X;
Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Matrix<double,3,1,Eigen::RowMajor,3,100>> Y;
Parameters par = Parameters()
point_to_point(X,Y,Parameters)
```

It gave me this error

```
error: ‘Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>::MatrixBase() [with Derived = Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 1, 3, 100>]’ is protected
     MatrixBase() : Base() {}
```

I also tried `Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Matrix4f> X;` but every type seems to be protected. What does it mean exactly?

I searched a lot but didn't find any example of `MatrixBase`.

- How can I insert/remove values in `Eigen::MatrixBase` - didn't find any such function [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html)?
- How can I convert my `pcl::PointCloud` to `Eigen::MatrixBase` and reverse?
- How can I call this function?

Comment: There is a function `PointCloud::getMatrixXfMap()` which allows to get access to the Eigen matrix "behind" the point cloud. I haven't tested it, but I think what this function returns should be implicitly castable to `MatrixBase`. One problem though is that in PCL the points are in row-major, i.e. point coordinates are on rows. The ICP algorithm that you want to run expects them to be arranged in columns.

Comment: `PointCloud::getMatrixXfMap()` returns `Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXf, Eigen::Aligned, Eigen::OuterStride<> >`. To what I need to cast it into? Its not allowing me to take a type and declare a `MatrixBase` variable.

Comment: How can I add all the points from the cloud one by one into the `MatrixBase<xxx>`, and reverse?

Comment: As I said, I think that the compiler will make appropriate casts implicitly. Simply pass whatever `getMatrixXfMap()` returns to the function.

Comment: AFAIK `MatrixBase` is not supposed to be instantiated by user code. As the name suggest, this is a base class for all matrices in Eigen. Therefore, when a function has a parameter of type `MatrixBase` it means that you can pass an argument of type `VectorXf`, `MatrixXf`, etc.

Comment: It didn't work. Rather it gave me [this](http://pastebin.com/K5gQv1YZ) error.

Comment: Hmm, it does not accept a map because the reference is not `const` (the function wants to modify its contents). Another problem is that inside the function the matrix scalar type is assumed to be `double` (because `VectorXd`, `Vector3d`, etc. classes are used), whereas PCL clouds consist of `float`s. Considering this, I would suggest to create a new `MatrixXd`, fill it with the data from the point cloud, and pass it to the function. Not optimal, but seems that there is no way to avoid data copying.

Answer (score -1):

You can construct matrix using for loop. For example

```
Eigen::Matrix3Xd X, Y;
    for (size_t idx = 0; idx != pc_X->size(); ++idx) {
        X.col(idx) = Eigen::Vector3d{pc_X->at(idx).x, 
                    pc_X->at(idx).y, 
                    pc_X->at(idx).z};
    }
    for (size_t idx = 0; idx != pc_Y->size(); ++idx) {
        Y.col(idx) = Eigen::Vector3d{pc_Y->at(idx).x, pc_Y->at(idx).y, pc_Y->at(idx).z};
    }
```